# How can I access my gmail using python imaplib and then classify them into travel and non travel mail

Tags: python

Approach would be
a. Write an access script to seek permission to your gmail account
b. After access is granted, classify each of the email and dump travel related email into separate folder or mark it appropriately

```
m = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com") 
m.login(user,pwd) 
m.select("cs2043") 
# here you a can choose a mail box like INBOX instead 
#  use m.list() to get all the mailboxes
```

I have got following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "gmail.py", line 9, in m.login(user,pwd) 
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/imaplib.py", line 507, in login raise self.error(dat[-1]) imaplib.error: [ALERT] 
Please log in via your web browser: support.google.com/mail/accounts/answer/78754 (Failure)
```

Comment: Can you provide any details of your current work? It sounds like an idea.

Comment: # connecting to the gmail imap server
m = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com")
m.login(user,pwd)
m.select("cs2043") # here you a can choose a mail box like INBOX instead
# use m.list() to get all the mailboxes  I have got following error : Traceback (most recent call last):
File "gmail.py", line 9, in 
m.login(user,pwd)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/imaplib.py", line 507, in login
raise self.error(dat[-1])
imaplib.error: [ALERT] Please log in via your web browser: https://support.google.com/mail/accounts/answer/78754 (Failure)